# i got a questions when i use iOS-Universal-Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, entity-framework

The iOS-Universal-Framework's page : https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

I have build my framework by use this template,i have pack all my class in the template，
but i got a problem,there some third-party framework that i want put in my framework depend on Appdelegate,but there is no Appdelegate class in the the iOS-Universal-Framework project，so i tried to add a "MyAppdelegate" class in my framework project

```
//
//  MyAppdelegate.h
//  ZPFramework
//
//  Created by Jin XuDong on 13-11-30.
//  Copyright (c) 2013年 Jin XuDong. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAppdelegate : UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate>

@end



//
//  MyAppdelegate.m
//  ZPFramework
//
//  Created by Jin XuDong on 13-11-30.
//  Copyright (c) 2013年 Jin XuDong. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyAppdelegate.h"

@implementation MyAppdelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // do somethinig depandes on appdelegate
}

@end
```

,then i inherit MyAppdelegate in my project which use my ZPFramework,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ZPFramework/MyAppDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate :MyAppDelegate  <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

but..it crashed immediately when the project run

```
    2013-11-30 10:46:16.771 维派[181:60b] -[AppDelegate setWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1655ebc0
2013-11-30 10:46:16.779 维派[181:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1655ebc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30970f4b 0x3ad006af 0x309748e7 0x30973069 0x308c24d8 0x8767b 0x331542ff 0x33153d4f 0x3314e353 0x330e941f 0x330e8721 0x3314db3d 0x3558470d 0x355842f7 0x3093b9df 0x3093b97b 0x3093a14f 0x308a4c27 0x308a4a0b 0x3314cdd9 0x33148049 0x80e09 0x3b208ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

i don't know why,please help me,thanks.

Comment: i tough you have used in xcode5

Comment: check your Target Dependencies